# function help. trying to print list1 what is missing

Tags: python, function

```
def main():
    list1=[]
    getdate(list1)
    print(list1)

def getdate():
    month = 1
    list1.append(month)
    return
```

I am trying to print list1 with using a function what am I doing wrong honestly? its such a simple program I really think its right but I don't know

Comment: The problem is that `list1` is that `getdate` does not expect a parameter. You need to `def getdate(list1):`...

Comment: Hint: functions don't do anything unless you call them.

Comment: so when I define get date as "def getdate(list1):" that's how it should be? is that what your sayng?

Answer (score 0):

you have defined a `function getdate()` and that should get a input value as you've called the function with one!
And also, the return value should be the list and that should be stored back into some variable!

> If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that
>   block.

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html) should help!

```
def main():
    list1=[]
    list1 = getdate(list1)
    print(list1)

def getdate(list1):
    month = 1
    list1.append(month)
    return list1
```

Output:

```
Keerthanas-MacBook-Air:Desktop kiran$ py test.py
[1]
Keerthanas-MacBook-Air:Desktop kiran$
```

or if list1 is a global variable!

```
list1=[]
def main():
    global list1
    getdate()
    print(list1)

def getdate():
    global list1
    month = 1
    list1.append(month)
```

Comment: It does give some output!

Answer (score 0):

here's what you want to do:

```
def get_date():
    return 1

def main():
    dates = []
    dates.append(get_date())
    print(dates)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

your main problem, pun intended, is that you weren't calling `main` anywhere. there were other problems that are fixed here as well.